# Windows Defender - Add exclusion folder programmatically

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender

I was checking out different keyloggers for research purposes and stumbled upon Refog:

https://www.refog.com/keylogger/

This program could catch a lot of system events, but what really caught my attention was something else. The program created a hidden folder called Mpk, path C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Mpk. It was marked as an operating system files folder, because it was not visible until I unmarked `Hide protected operating system files (recommended)`. This, I guess, can be done via the attrib command like this `attrib +s +h "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Mpk"` so nothing revolutionary.

[image: Hide]

However they also added an exclusion to Windows Defender for this folder. How can they do this programmatically? I'm running Windows 10 Pro x64.

[image: Exclusion]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The correct way to do this is using the Add-MpPreference PowerShell cmdlet. Use this cmdlet to add exclusions for file name extensions, paths, and processes, and to add default actions for high, moderate, and low threats.

You can easily perform this from the elevated cmd shell in Windows 10 using the following command line:

```
powershell -inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Mpk"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, however if you have a space in your file path the command needs to be escaped, like this: `powershell -inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command "Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\sysconfig'"`

Comment: How can I do this with more than one path please? @balrob

Comment: A comma separated list (with no spaces around the comma) should do it, e.g `-ExclusionPath 'path1','path2'`

Comment: Use the following to confirm the changes: `powershell -inputformat none -outputformat text -NonInteractive -Command Get-MpPreference`

Comment: .. or check Windows Defender settings configuration in it to see the changes.

Answer (score 22):

Run in elevated shell (search cmd in Start menu and hit <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd>).

```
powershell -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\tmp"
powershell -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionProcess "java.exe"
powershell -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionExtension ".java"

powershell -Command Remove-MpPreference -ExclusionExtension ".java"
```

- [Add an exclusion to Windows Security](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security)
- [Modifies settings for Windows Defender from PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/add-mppreference)
- [Removes exclusions or default actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/remove-mppreference)

Comment: Consider the risk it may cause: if you really exclude all the `Temp` folder, every app can download suspicious files and you won't get notified anymore.

Comment: You are right. As soon as it's not a system temp folder, it's fine.

Comment: adding java.exe exclusion is a serious security threat!

Comment: I like how you show both *adding* and *removing* an exclusion and also point to the correct documentation. I've used this to install NirLauncher from chocolatey, temporarily excluding the chocolatey directory (which is under the `%TEMP%` of the current user: not a location to permanently allow.

Exclude: `powershell -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "%TEMP%\chocolatey\NuGetScratch"`
Install: `choco update --yes nirlauncher` 
Remove exclusion: `powershell -Command Remove-MpPreference -ExclusionPath` "%TEMP%\chocolatey\NuGetScratch"`

Comment: For those who complains about security risks: those are just examples! Useful because it reports the three cases and the remove case.

Answer (score 11):

After some digging I found the following folder:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Paths
```

I cannot add a key there with my user. I get the following error: `Cannot create key: You do not have the requisite permissions to create a new key under Paths`

However SYSTEM, WinDefend and TrustedInstaller all have *Full Control*. The best guess is that they have used something like DevxExec `devxexec.exe /user:TrustedInstaller cmd` and written the key to the registry.

[image]

Comment: No. Each user has its own registry.

Comment: If you vote down please say why. Hard to improve answers otherwise

Answer (score 3):

Go to powershell

Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\Temp"

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/add-mppreference?view=win10-ps

Comment: Consider the risk it may cause: if you really exclude all the `Temp` folder, every app can download suspicious files and you won't get notified anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is using PowerShell from CMD with elevated privileges (like [balrob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233123/windows-defender-add-exclusion-folder-programmatically/45339380#45339380)), but you can also use the PowerShell environment variables to make your life easier; for example:

```
powershell -inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath $ENV:USERPROFILE\Downloads
```

which will add current user's Downloads folder, eg. C:\Users\Susana\Downloads.

To get the list of environment variables provided by PowerShell, you can use this PowerShell command:

```
Get-ChildItem Env: | Sort Name
```

As you can see, there is the *windir* variable. They could use that in addition with the subfolders you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought that I would post this as it did take me a few seconds to figure out how to do this in C# but here is the code that is working for me:

```
        var elevated = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell")
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            Verb = "runas",
            Arguments = " -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath '" + directory + "'"
        };
        Process.Start(elevated);
```