# Gradle downloads triggers Windows Defender - how can I exclude files downloaded in Temp folder

Tags: gradle, windows-defender

When I use Gradle, Windows Defender keeps popping up and want to send the files to their server. The download file has this pattern:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_downloadxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbin
```

Can I exclude them with file mask? I don't see it in the settings of Windows Defender.

I don't want to exclude the whole folder because I want other downloaded files to be scanned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I have found this:

[Windows Defender - Add exclusion folder programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233123/windows-defender-add-exclusion-folder-programmatically)

with elevated cmd, you can do:(change `me` to your username)

```
powershell -inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download*"
```

And check Windows Defender settings, you will see your mask there. It is working now.

Comment: Use with caution though, maybe some malware will disguise themselves as these gradle download files? Remember to check them regularly.